# Too many initializer values

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a pointer to a two-dimensional array which I have declared like this:

```
int **gameBoard[3][3];
```

Then added this to the class constructor:

```
**gameBoard = { 
                {0,0,0}, 
                {0,0,0}, //<--that's the specific line I am getting the error in
                {0,0,0} 
              };
```

I even declared it as a `20x20` but I get the same error every time:

```
too many initializer values
```

Any help?

Comment: That's a two-dimensional array of pointers to pointers, and `**gameBoard` is equivalent to `gameBoard[0][0]`, which is *one* pointer – an `int**`.

Comment: Or use vector of vectors instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare and initialize the two dimensional array like this:

```
int gameBoard[3][3] = { 
                {0,0,0}, 
                {0,0,0}, 
                {0,0,0} 
                };
```